# How to toggle tags in a MongoDB array?

Tags: mongodb

With a schema like this :

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("513fe2b85b51eafc15000023"),
        "tags" : [
                "House",
                "Red"
        ]
}
```

How would you do the following:

If the tag exists remove it, if it doesn't exist add it.

Comment: Do you query based on the `_id` field?

Comment: Did you get a solution? I am looking for one update statement to toggle tags in a array as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) and [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/). `$addToSet` will only add the tag if it doesn't exist. `$pull` will remove all instances of the tag.

As @assylias mentioned, you would construct a full update command with the `_id` presumabley, or in conjunction with `{tags: tagInQuestion}` to only operate on a document that has `tagInQuestion` etc.

Comment: Yeah, but how to know when to use one over the other, suposing that you're using a GraphQL API and can't diferentiate by the HTTP verb used.